# Importar tabela de página da web para Excel

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Quero pegar todos os dados de uma tabela da internet e colocá-los no excel.
Tentei com ocódigo abaixo, mas aparece o seguinte erro na linha do 'For Each':

> "Erro em tempo de execução '438':  Objeto não aceita esta propriedade
>   ou método"

```
Sub CCEE_precoMedio()

Dim ie As Object
Dim doc As Object, elem As Object, trow As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Navigate "https://www.ccee.org.br/portal/faces/pages_publico/o-que-fazemos/como_ccee_atua/precos/precos_medios?_adf.ctrl-state=trut1o6ix_5&_afrLoop="
ie.Visible = True

    Do Until (ie.readyState = 4 And Not ie.Busy)
        DoEvents
    Loop

Set doc = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("displaytag-Table_soma")

   r = 1
    For Each elem In doc.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        For Each trow In elem.getElementsByTagName("td")
            y = y + 1: Cells(r + 1, y + 1) = trow.innerText
        Next trow
        y = 0
        r = r + 1

    Next elem

End Sub
```

Acredito que p erro esteja em como referencio o item. Como corrijo isso?

Comment: A tabela está dentro de um iFrame, então o iFrame deve ser acessado primeiro. `<iframe id="pt1:myFrame" class="xhg xwr p_AFFlow" frameborder="0" src="/preco/precoMedio.do" onload="AdfDhtmlInlineFramePeer.__iframeLoadHandler(event)" _adfloaded="1" height="4633" style="min-width: 0px; min-height: 0px; visibility: visible; height: 4618px;"></iframe>`

Comment: Deu certo Daniel! Valeu